# How come my Node.js heap memory footprint is much smaller than expected after reading a big file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a ~2GB big file and am reading it in Node.js with the readline module and push each line into an array like so:

```
const readline = require("readline");
const fs = require("fs");
const filePath = "./bigfile";

async function read(file) {
  const lines = [];

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(file),
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    lines.push(line);
  }

  const used = process.memoryUsage();
  for (let key in used) {
    console.log(`Memory: ${key} ${Math.round(used[key] / 1024 / 1024)} MB`);
  }
}
read(filePath);
```

The file size:

```
$ ls -l bigfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 kg 197121 2075855634 Okt 25 11:59 bigfile
```

I expected that that heapUsed would be somewhat close to ~2GB given the fact that I read all the lines into an array but the output looks like so:

```
$ node readBigFile.js
Memory: rss 484 MB
Memory: heapTotal 463 MB
Memory: heapUsed 441 MB
Memory: external 3 MB
Memory: arrayBuffers 2 MB
```

Is Node.js compressing its memory?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not a Node guy, but I wonder if this is due to operations being lazy; you can make an experiment, printing every line read to stdout.

Comment: I think I'd wait a long time to write every line to. IIRC `console.log()` is synchronous and the file contains 32 million lines.